# Sorting 30k record SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Hi everyone can any body help me with this problem?
I have a backup copy of our client database from Production server.
Our client have a issue. There's a long time queries and I found out that when I include the ORDER BY columnA in the script.

**First test in production:**
The result in SQL Profiler in our production READ is too much big and also there's a WRITE process and the execution time took 20 seconds plus. But when I remove the ORDER BY columnA the result in SQL Profiler in our production the execution time is 2 seconds only and without WRITE process.

**Second test in my local machine using restoring client database:**
The result in SQL Profiler in my local machine with READ without WRITE execution time is 2 seconds. When I remove the ORDER BY columnA the result in SQL Profiler is almost the same with column sorting.

In summary.
Test in production: 
WITH ORDER BY columnA
HIGH READ AND WRITE
WITHOUT ORDER BY columnA
HIGH READ without WRITE

Test in local machine:
WITH ORDER BY columnA
LOW READ WITHOUT RIGHT
WITHOUT ORDER BY columnA
LOW READ WITHOUT RIGHT.

I'm confuse a little bit because I cannot work alone with our client production. As a Database Administrator this is one of my challenge. To test it locally without touching the Production Server.

Executional Plan from my local machine using MSSQL 2014 SQL Express:
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SyI__nPeZ

Comment: The first thing that comes to mind: with a local machine the memory is all yours whereas in the production machine many processes may have to share it. Sorting is a costly operation. So: invest in hardware and extend your production machine, I'd say. If it's just about one query, however, you might want to create an appropriate covering index.

Comment: with that I already found out that they did not change the default value of allotted memory in production server. Production server total memory is 22GB while SQL already consumed 21.8GB.

Comment: I'd highly recommend looking at @MiloBellano's comment about creating an index that includes the sorted column. You may want to include the _read_ query (or at least columns) and there is a chance we could assist in creating an accurate index. Related indexing information: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181154(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Including that. Please check that in my local machine I have the same copy of the client database. That only take 2 seconds to process. Means everything is already set up well in terms of indexing for clustered and non clustered index.

Comment: You did not say nothing about your query, is that one-table select * from MyTable where MyTable's cardinality is 30K or the quary has 20 tables (1 mln each) in join with the resultset that counts 30K record?

Comment: Inner join multiple table resulting 30k rows. Local machine means my local computer

Comment: @MiloBellano how can you advice to create an index without seeing the query? This could look like select * from MyTable order by ColA which selects all 100 fields from the table. So what happend when you add an index on ColA? It will not be used anyway, there will be a full table scan anyway

Comment: That's what I said just now: >>>Inner join multiple table resulting 30k rows. So it's not a one-table query and it can select multiple columns. So what's making difference is an Execution Plan. One should compare 2 execution plans from one server and another.

Comment: Actually query above edited question.

Comment: The edited post has no SELECT list, and it matters

Comment: A sidenote: You can have different suppliers (TBL_BestellingRegels.SupplierId) for the same order (TBL_Bestellingen)? That looks strange.

Comment: Do not focus on the script. It is more on the process behind issue. The script is already sitting for more than 10 years.

Comment: Post the execution plans for resulting from running on both 2008R2 and 2014 to pastetheplan.com and update your post with the links to each.

Comment: Will do that tom. Will update you all

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I'd aggregate before joining.

```
  SELECT 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR, B.[Id]) AS Id,
    (SELECT Value FROM dbo.FN_System_SetLeading0(B.UID, 6)) AS Nummer,
    B.ColumnA,
    L.Naam AS Leverancier,
    B.Naam AS Naam,
    (SELECT Value FROM dbo.FN_Sys_LoadTrans('TBL_Status.' + CAST(B.statusId AS VARCHAR) + '.1', 13, 'statussen')) AS status,
    (SELECT Value FROM dbo.FN_System_LoadSupplierCurrencyDisplay(L.[id], 'HTML')) AS TotaalPrijsValuta,
    BR.TotaalPrijs
  FROM TBL_Bestellingen B
  INNER JOIN 
  (
    SELECT 
      BestellingenId, SupplierId,
      CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,2), SUM(Prijs * Hoeveelheid + ExtraKosten)) AS TotaalPrijs
    FROM TBL_BestellingRegels 
    WHERE Datumverwijderd IS NULL
      AND StatusId BETWEEN 65 AND 65
      AND SupplierId = CASE WHEN 0 > 0 THEN 0 ELSE BR.SupplierId END
    GROUP BY BestellingenId, SupplierId
  ) BR ON BR.BestellingenId = B.Id
  INNER JOIN TBL_Leveranciers L ON BR.SupplierId = L.Id
  WHERE B.WerkmaatschappijenId IN (SELECT LocationId FROM dbo.FN_General_GetList(3))
  AND B.Datumverwijderd IS NULL
  ORDER BY B.ColumnA DESC
```

Then I'd try these covering indexes:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_b ON TBL_Bestellingen(WerkmaatschappijenId, Datumverwijderd, ColumnA, ID, UID, Naam, statusId);

CREATE INDEX idx_br ON TBL_BestellingRegels(StatusId, SupplierId, Datumverwijderd, BestellingenId);
```

Comment: Hi @Thorsten Kettner. I will try that suggestion tom.

Answer (score 0):

Add an index on the column you are sorting by. It is difficult to help you without knowing it's mssql, mysql, redshift etc...
If you have a sql workbench, right click on name of the table, add index and add it on the column you need to sort. If it is by command line, check your sql version index documentation. If you share more details, then I can suggest which index will be better....

Comment: I have already the index for those table. Production server is using MS SQL 2008 R2. While my local machine is currently running in MS SQL 2014. I work as a Database Administrator but I don't know why they did not understand that as a DBA I am the one who must have a admin role

Comment: I can't comment above as I am a new user. I have suggested index because maybe one machine was older/less powerful than the other, and I have assumed query was joining something, mr sepupic. Anyway, I have assumed you were doing something more complex than a select * from table (like joining stuff) if FK and PK you join on are set correctly, indexed right, I'd say check exec plans and maybe your customer machine is just older than your with different sql version as well. It's like if I try to run something on work server it is super fast but if I do it locally on my machine it will run forever

Comment: The question included "SQL Server" in the title and was tagged with `sql-server` right from the start. So it **is** clear which DBMS JGamis is using

Comment: No it is not clear if it is 2012, 2014 or whatever.........have you ever tried to run 2012 scripts on 2014? I did, not always everything is the same. Or do you think exist ONE mssql ? Geeeee we are here trying to help not to be nasty and arrogant, anyway, hope he will fix the issue because I understand how it is frustrating

Comment: This one is making sense. Please read the whole details. I think everything you need is there

Comment: if you have 2008 and 2014, believe me things are different. Could be your join order is different in the exec plan, I think first suggestion of check exec plans and compare was good.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server 2014 has a new cardinality estimator that differs from 2008R2. You will not get the answer 
until you compare both execution plans. Your problem is not in sorting the resultset, it's more probable you have different join / group algorithms in your plans. Not only explisit ORDER BY clause use sort that can spill into tempdb, but algorithms as merge join / group by also

Comment: no sepupic. As i said I already tried executing exact script above. With and without sorting. And there is a large difference.

Comment: I insist on looking into execution plans. With or without order by the plan can change, but not only in ordering the resultset, it can affect the choice of grouping algorithm, it can use hash aggregate (without sort) or stream aggregate (sort!). I think the aggregate operator in your plan cost much more than final sorting, even if it's the final order by that affects the aggregate algorithm choice

Comment: @JGamis that's the point. The new Cardinality Estimator in SQL Server 2014 may yield very different execution plans **for the same query** when compared to previous versions of SQL Server and therefore you **must** examine each execution plan to find the difference - it may not be where you think it is.